# Master to mister?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, formality, politeness

Why was Master weakened to Mister so as to address individual hominēs sapientēs and the English language lost the thou/you distinction while the Greek language kept both Kύριος intact and the Eσύ/Eσείς distinction?

Sir comes from Senex and I am not confortable with using Sir knowing it is a cognate with Senille.

Maybe a sociolinguistic approach would best explain this particular fact.

The Greeks most often earnestly use the plural Εσείς to address any adult(or even children older than 13 years old) that has not requested to quit formallities.

Comment: [linguistics.se] may chip in.

Comment: @Kris Is it honestly an invitation fot them to chip in and my question is on-topic. Or is it an indirect jab directed at me so I post the question there instead of here as it is off-topic here?

Comment: I s'pose the mods will do the needful either way.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396731/why-does-master-mean-man-and-boy

Comment: My question though was not about Master being weakened. My question is not exhausted in this word change. My question was a bit more general. It was about Etiquette and Formality. The core is not the word Master but the polite and formal way to address someone. Both Mister/Master and Thou/You. There are Greeks that get offended when one addresses them in the singular or with their names. I am afraid to do anything with the question though even if I believe it does not capture the core of my question.

Comment: _Sir_ is not cognate with _senile_ – it comes from the same root, yes, but that doesn’t make it a cognate. _Senate/senator_ comes from the same root, too. I’m not sure what you’re saying the commonality is between the reduction from _master_ to _mister_ and the loss of the old singular pronoun. They are two completely separate developments that have nothing to do with each other. Also, you say Greek _kept_ the T–V distinction intact, but in fact they _introduced_ it – it’s a relatively new phenomenon, completely unknown in Ancient Greek.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am not saying there is any commonality. I am asking why Master became Mister AND there was a loss of the old singular pronoun while the Greek language kept Κύριε intact AND introduced(rather than keeping) the  T-V distinction( Sure Alexander and Diogenes spoke in the Tu form but the T-V distinction was introduced soon after the Greek Liberation at mid 19 century It has been almost 2 centuries since).

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos You should probably split it up into two questions, then, since they’re not really related (though I believe the formality question has been asked before – there’s probably an existing question that explains it). We prefer questions that deal with just one topic here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But the topic is not Master->Mister and T-V distinction it is a topic that covers both. Etiquette and Formallity.

Answer (score 2):

*How ‘master’ became ‘mister’*  [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2017/05/mister.html)

> - > In late Middle English, people began using “Mr.,” an abbreviated
>   >     version of “master,” as a title “prefixed to the surname or first name
>   >     of a man without a higher, honorific, or professional title,”
>   >     according to the OED.
> - When people began speaking it, “Mr.” was pronounced like “master,”    but “from the 16th cent. it was, at least in rapid or careless
>     speech, with consequent alteration of the    vowel of the first
>     syllable,” according to the dictionary.

The first written example in the OED for the word spelled “mister” is from a 1642, and as the article notes it was a convoluted semantic shift of convenience, not one motivated by slave, master, Mr. etc.  Even now, with master freed from mister, master can be used for juvenile men ... but its use now fades, probably for now extant political correctness.

So, why was Master weakened to Mister? It was simple semantic shift for brevity of abbreviations. There were dozens of different spellings for master. Brevity here meaning ... for lack of a better term, laziness and (economy) of language, not some early politically correct mid period BrE.

Comment: "Even now, with master freed from mister and can be used for juvenile men ... it use to fades.

So, why was Master weakened to Mister? A simple emantic shift for brevity of abbreviations, not some early politically correct mid period BrE."  Could you please improve on the last 3 sentences as it is hard for me to understand what you mean?

Comment: edited.........

Comment: Thank you earnestly. I can still not understand the segments "and can be used for juvenile men ... it use to fades."  and "not some early politically correct mid period BrE." Would it be "being used(its use being allowed) for juvenile men.... its use fades too" I do not want to assume which was the intended meaning I like clarity fro safety reasons. The second segment though is really an enigma.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos the "used for juvenile men" comes from the last century probably. I remember receiving mail on my birthday as a child addressed to "Master J---"

Comment: 19th century servants would address young sons of the family  as 'Master John' and the like. Until at least the mid-20th century, the convention was to address mail for young boys to 'Master John Smith', as Cascabel notes. The usage is 'fading' because it's common nowadays not to use any title when addressing envelopes, whatever the recipient's age.

Comment: @Cascabel The wording was(now it is not anymore) the problem. But I cannot understand the for brevity as opposed to some early politically correct mid period BrE(I would guess the acronym would stand for British English). My bad if I am pedantic and fail to see the bigger picture.

Comment: My question was Why it changed not How. I am looking for a reason as an answer I did not ask for an explanation of the process. The Greeks should have been as lazy as the English were. We use a lot of abbreviations too Κ. for Κύριος and Κα for Κυρία. And we also use the plural number when in doubt of whether it would be appropriate to address someone in the singular. What were supposed to be the reasons that caused English these changes did not cause them in Greek.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Unlike some countries (such as Spain with their DRAE) which try to protect the "purity" of the language, English does not have a real "Why" to explain organic changes in the usage. The explanation of the process _is_ the "how' and "why". For some reason you seem to be expecting a situation in which social changes in Greece should affect language in the rest of the world  or vice versa... i.e. "What were supposed to be the reasons that caused English these changes did not cause them in Greek."

Comment: @Cascabel I am earnestly sorry if I appear to be expecting social changes in Greece to affect the rest of the word. But a good explanation would be how the society was different. If society was different it could cause the differences in language development. Otherwise Κύριος was not weakened even if it is frequently abreviated like Master was while the T-V distinction was introduces instead of lost. Social differences between the place the language is spoken could explain why English is the way it is.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was just on the point of saying..."That is way beyond the scope of our site." Try Linguistics.SE. It _is_ an interesting question...There is also some correlation with Korean and Russian from the same period of time. I have written on that previously on SE.

Comment: I am not sure I'm buying that. Did everyone forget what it sounds like, or did writing introduce the term to ta broader spectrum? Cp *mini, mice*, as if "mister" was opposite to "master". Also cp Ger *Muster* "master [key, piece, cd?], prototype, sample, pattern, role-model, good student, etc" perhaps via "measure", if only regarding the schoolboy sense. Regarding the vocalism compare e.g. *Kuss* "kiss", *Hügel* "hill", *Kasten* ~ *Kiste*, *just* ~ *je*, *hoch* "high"; one could speculate.

Comment: @Cascabel I haven't been able to get an answer https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/33815/which-are-the-social-differences-which-lead-to-the-variance-in-the-way-to-addres